# How do I fix an exception thrown during unit testing because SQLite doesn't have a certain function defined in HasDefaultValueSql?

Tags: sqlite, unit-testing, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have the following configuration for a BaseEntity that every other entity derives from:

```
    entityTypeBuilder.Property(e => e.CreatedDate)
        .HasColumnType("timestamp without time zone")
        .HasDefaultValueSql("NOW()")
        .IsRequired();
```

I am using SQLite in my Unit tests but since addition of this field, they have started to throw an exception about "NOW()". How do I fix this?

Comment: Uh... Don't use non-existent functions?

Comment: `timestamp without time zone` will probably be accepted by sqlite because it's very, very loose about what can be used as a data type in a column definition, but is basically meaningless. See https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html

Comment: @Shawn I use PostgreSQL as my database provider and that's why I need this function.

Comment: Then you should be using postgresql in your testing too.

Comment: You can try to replace `NOW()` with `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: @Shawn you can't use Postgresql in unit testing in with EF Core.

Comment: Sounds like a major flaw with either your testing framework or this EF Core if you can't use the same database engine for testing and production.